# i'm getting segmentation fault(core dumped) when i execute this code...

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* get_page(char *s)
{
FILE *fp = fopen(s,"r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("file not found\n");
    }else{
        char c;
        char *a;
        int y,i;
        a=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*100000);
        for(i=0;(c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF;i++){
            a[i]=c;
        }
        a[i+1]='\0';
        fclose(fp);
        return a;
    }
}
char** get_all_links(char *b)
{
    //printf("%s",b);
    int u,i=0,j=0,t,z;
    char **f;
    f=(char **) malloc(sizeof(char *)*100);
    u=strlen(b);
    for(t=0;t<u;t++){
            if(b[t]=='<' && (b[t+1]=='A' || b[t+1]=='a')){
                f[j]=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10000);
                for(z=t+9;b[z]!='"';z++){
                    f[j][i++]=b[z];
                }
                i=0;
                j++;
            }
    }
    printf("%d\n",j);
    if(j==0){
        f[0]=NULL;
    }else{
        f[j+1]=NULL;
    }
    return f;
}
int main(){
    char f[100],*p,*l,*w,**k,**links;
    scanf("%s",f);
    int loop_count=0,ii,prev_links=0,check=0,get_link=1,o,u;
    k=NULL;
    while(f!=NULL){
        //printf("in while 1\n");
    printf("%s\n",f);
    p=get_page(f);
    //printf("%s",p);
    if(k!=NULL)
        free(k);
    k=get_all_links(p);
    //printf("\n");
    int count_for_links=0,x=0;
    while(k[x]!=NULL){
        //printf("in while\n");
        count_for_links++;
        x++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count_for_links);
    prev_links=prev_links+count_for_links;
    if(loop_count==0){
        //printf("in loop count ==0\n");
    links=(char **) malloc(sizeof(char *)*(count_for_links+1));
    links[0]=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(f));
    strcpy(links[0],f);
    //printf("%s\n",links[0]);
    for(ii=0;ii<count_for_links;ii++){
        //printf("in for ii<count_for_links\n");
        links[ii+1]=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(k[ii]));
        strcpy(links[ii+1],k[ii]);
        printf("%s\n",links[ii+1]);
    }
    }else if(loop_count>0){
        //printf("%s\n",k[0] );
        for(o=0;(k[o]!=NULL && o<count_for_links);o++){
            printf("%s",k[o]);
            //printf("check extra %d\n",loop_count);
            for(u=0;u<=ii;u++){
                if(strcmp(k[o],links[u])==1){
                    check=1;
                    printf("the war");
                }
            }

            if(check==0){
            //  printf("in link not found\n");
                links =(char **) realloc(links,(sizeof(char *)));
                links[ii+1]=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(k[o]));
                ii++;
                strcpy(links[ii],k[o]);
            }   
        }
    }
    printf("OUT");
    strcpy(f,links[get_link]);
    get_link++;
    loop_count++;
}
int q;
printf("helloooooo");
for(q=0;links[q]!=NULL;q++){
printf("%s",links[q]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

/*here in this code the k array represents the links that i get from a html and for first time it stores in links array and from next time it checks other page and if links are same it omits the same links and takes the other links into the array */

Comment: Hi There. Why don't you check it with a debugger first? LIke `gdb`.

Comment: If you aren't going to use a debugger: "divide and conquer" - add some prints to narrow down the crash. I can see at least 3 places where a NULL check should be added...

Comment: where i have to add null ?

Comment: thank you john3136 ... my code is now working :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if your file is greater than 100.000 you will write over :

```
a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 100000);   <--
    for (i = 0; (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; i++){
        a[i] = c;
    }
```

you should use file size perhaps